# Force Apache to treat HTTP as HTTPS with Cloudfront SSL/TLS

Tags: apache-2.4

I've a CloudFront Distribution that uses AWS Certificate for SSL/TLS requests coming from `https://example.com` and an origin that forwards those requests to EC2.

The Distribution is set to use HTTP protocol between itself and origin (EC2) and behavior is set to `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` such that any `http://example.com` are redirected to `https://example.com`.

The EC2 has an Apache server that serves file. However, when I visit `https://example.com` all static resources (css, js) are being served over HTTP which are blocked by the broser due to `loading mixed active content`.

My current Apache configuration only has default `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` with `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:443>` does not exist. Also, I did not create `<VirtualHost *:443>` since I do not have certs and keys for SSL.

How do I solve this issue? Is it possible through reverse proxy? What would be the best practice here?

Update:
My setup is same as described in this answer but without the ELB https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453691/1197636.

Comment: This is caused by your web application. You will need to reconfigure it to use relative paths or https absolute URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let Apache know that you're behind a load balancer. This is done by the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. This can be set either in your virtual host config or in .htaccess.

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
```

Another important part is to configure your framework/code to serve content over https. If you have hard coded URLs, etc. Start with the header and work from there

Comment: Can you share an example for `X-Forwarded-Proto`? I added the `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"` in `<VirtualHost *:80></VH>` but that didn't work.

Comment: Turns out adding it to both places, VH and .htaccess does work. But it doesn't work only adding it in a single place.